# WCF ServiceAuthenticationManager Extensibility

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I want to implement my custom security to wcf,I want to use ServiceAuthenticationManager ,but I am confused how it can be block the message.I tried to throw exception but that time I cannot get my exception detail I got just "request error" in rest call and "The caller was not authenticated by the service" in soap calls but I cant get my custom error error message,What is the correct usage of ServiceAuthenticationManager,or where should I block message?

```
public class MyAuthenticationManager :  ServiceAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> Authenticate(ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> authPolicy, Uri listenUri, ref Message message)
    {
        //throw new AuthenticationException("Credentials expired!");
        throw new SecurityException("my custom message:Invalid authentication");
        return base.Authenticate(authPolicy, listenUri,ref message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you probably shouldn't be giving details to dubious clients as to why their authentication failed.  There is generally no need for custom errors

Answer (score 1):

Authentication/Authorization do not give custom messages. Any kind of indication *why* you are not authorized or authenticated are a way for an attacker to crack your security or gain information he is not entitled to.

For example saying "Your password is wrong" is an indication that the username *exists*. That is bad. An unauthorized request should never get such information as a response.

If *you* want to see what went wrong, write to a log that the server administrator can access. But don't send anything to the client. Ever.

So to summarize: no you cannot get a custom message out and that design is on purpose.

Comment: WCF Rest return message is not identical for serviceauthenticationmanager for that reason I want to give custom error message,by the way throw exception in serviceauthenticationmanager ,Is right approach to interrupt message?what is your suggestion?